# Does the tutor's proof make sense? If not, how would you prove this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, exponentiation

I'm taking an online course in Discrete Maths. The course starts by explaining the need for proofs, by presenting a proof to an example problem. The way the tutor presents the proof does not make sense to me. Can anyone explain, and if not, can you provide a better proof?

The problem:

*Find a number such that, after removing the first digit, it becomes the original number divided by 57*

The tutor gives one solution as 7125. And then starts the proof like this:

If we think of $b...z$ to be the remaining sequence of $k$ digits (after removing the first one) we can use $x$ to represent it, like this:

$ x = b...z$

And lets call the first digit which we removed, $a$. The digit $a$ is a value $0 \lt a \le 9$, and in the original number, it has been "shifted left" by $k$ places, i.e. it is that single digit multiplied by $10 ^ k$.

And the tutor goes through the following 3 steps:

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a \times 10^k + x = 57 \times x $

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a \times 10^k =\,\,\,\, 56 \times x \,\,\,\,= \,\,\,\,\, 7 \times 8 \times x $

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a \times (2^k \times 5^k) = 7 \times 8 \times x$

I understand it so far, but then the tutor states "here 7 cannot hide", while circling the expression $(2^k \times 5^k)$. I've taken "cannot hide" to mean *7 is obviously never a factor of*. Is that correct? And if so, how can you tell this simply by glancing at the expression?

Anyway, the tutor then concludes therefore that $a$ "must be divisible by 7", and because $a$ is a single digit, makes the following step:

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,7 \times (2^k \times 5^k) = 7 \times 8 \times x$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,10^k = 8 \times x$

So, going back to his solution 7125: $x$ is 125, and therefore $k$ is 3 (3 digits long), and it is true that 125 =  1000 $\div$ 8. Thus proving that $a$ is indeed 7.

But how did he make that leap about 7 not being a factor of $(2^k \times 5^k)$?

Comment: Please make titles descriptive about the *mathematics* of the post, and please use at least one tag that is related to the mathematical content of the post.

Comment: Are you familiar with unique factorization of positive integers? $7$ is a prime, as are $2$ and $5$. The only primes that divide a number of the form $2^a\times 5^b$ are $2$ and $5$.

Comment: Note that this was only the *smallest* solution of $10^k=8x.$

Comment: @Arturo, Ah I see. No I am not familiar with that idea. I'm very much a beginner. That's how he could make the leap. I will investigate.

Comment: He got that from The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Every positive integer greater than 1 is either prime or can be expressed uniquely as the product of primes raised to some power. For example $60=2^2\cdot3 \cdot 5$. Change a out any of the prime bases for some other prime or any exponent for some other exponent and you get a different product. Since a point is reached where the right side is divisible by 7, the left has to be 2. The product of powers of 2 and 5 are never divisible by 7 as a corollary, so $a$ must be.

Comment: @Turloc your comment, and your last sentence in particular, really helped me understand. What a great community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the other comments and answers the reason why $2^k \cdot 5^k$ is not divisible by $7$ if the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).
(If a number is divisible by $7$ it has $7$ as one of its prime factors, but the prime factors of $2^k \cdot 5^k$ are only $2$ and $5$)

The proof shows that the first digit of the number has to be $7$, so you are left with
$$
2^k \cdot 5^k=8 x \rightarrow \frac{2^k \cdot 5^k}{8}=x
$$
you know that the LHS has to be divisible by $8=2^3$ (because $x$ is an integer), so you have $k \ge 3$. This means that the smallest numbers that satisfies your theorem is $7125$, but you can choose $k$ bigger than $3$ and still obtain a valid result.
In particular, because your number can be written as
$$
7 \cdot 10^k +x=\left(7+\frac{1}{8} \right) \cdot 10^k
$$
and $\left(7+\frac{1}{8} \right) \cdot 10^3=7125$ if you choose $k>3$  your number becames $7125 \cdot 10^{k-3}$

Answer (score 0):

Since the term *a* has been shifted by *k* terms to the left, *k* must be a positive integral value. That being said, $(2^k \times 5^k)$ can never form a term that is a **multiple** of 7, and hence *a* must be a multiple of 7.

Since we originally considered *a* to lie in the range (0,9]; 7 is the only possible value of *a*. Since we had a term of $2^k$ in our expression, that **must** be equal to 8 , giving **k=3** and hence the number taken as *7125*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "that must be equal to 8"... why?

Comment: @centauri it is false. If $k=4$ and $x=2 \cdot 5^4=1250$ we have a perfect valid solution, indeed $\frac{71250}{57}=1250$

Comment: @centauri since a equals 7 and there is only one other term with its powers as 2, it would be 8 since the other term (5^k) cannot be raised to an integral power to form 8..